# SkyBox cannot set scale on Android Cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, skybox

With [cocos2d-x](/questions/tagged/cocos2d-x) v3.7.1 I have trouble using `setScale` on Android only (it works on iOS).

```
auto textureCube = TextureCube::create("sky_left.JPG", "sky_right.JPG","sky_top.JPG", "sky_bottom.JPG","sky_front.JPG", "sky_back.JPG");
textureCube->retain();
//create a skybox
auto skyBox = Skybox::create();
skyBox->retain();
//set cube texture to the skybox
skyBox->setTexture(textureCube);
skyBox->setScale(1000.0f);
addChild(skyBox);
```

Though I changed the value of `setScale`, it's completely the same view.

However in scene3DTest `setScale` is used and applied. What's the difference?

Comment: Thanks for editing, fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded what I made the mistake.
Add after camera created:

```
camera->setCameraFlag(CameraFlag::USER1);
setCameraMask(2);
```